# UnrecoverableKeyException Failed to obtain information about private key, KeyStoreException: Invalid key blob

Tags: android, private-key, android-keystore, android-security, java-security

In our app we've been having issues with data in the Android Keystore suddenly becoming inaccessible. The specific exception we're seeing is here:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Failed to obtain information about private key
 at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePublicKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:223)
 at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyPairFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:259)
 at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePrivateKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:269)
 at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:94)
 at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:474)
 at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1560)
 at <PACKAGE_NAME>.EncryptionInteractor.generateKeys(EncryptionInteractor.java:104)
 at <PACKAGE_NAME>.EncryptionInteractor.generateKeys(EncryptionInteractor.java:100)
 at <PACKAGE_NAME>.EncryptionInteractor.init(EncryptionInteractor.java:93)
 at <PACKAGE_NAME>.EncryptionInteractor.<init>(EncryptionInteractor.java:80)
 at <PACKAGE_NAME>.EncryptionInteractor.init(EncryptionInteractor.java:65)
 at <PACKAGE_NAME>.<APPLICATION_CLASS>.onCreate(APPLICATION_CLASS.java:17)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5791)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid key blob
 at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:695)
 at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePublicKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:224)
  ... 21 more
```

We have not been able to come up with a reliable way of reproducing the issue. Several articles mention possible states that can cause the Keystore to "forget" a Key or become locked such as [here](https://doridori.github.io/android-security-the-forgetful-keystore/#sthash.SPGO7JXV.wE9npzuE.dpbs). However, as far as I can tell we have not fallen into any of these edge cases. It seems to happen after letting the device sit for a while after the first setup of the key. We have seen this happen across multiple emulators and devices, ranging from  21 to 26. Additionally, these devices use either a swipe to unlock or a PIN. Changing the PIN or security method does not seem to cause the issue. Again, this issue seems to occur after the device has been sitting unused for several days.

I have found two other SOs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652675/java-security-unrecoverablekeyexception-failed-to-obtain-information-about-priv) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488219/android-security-keystoreexception-invalid-key-blob) as well as one Google [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/63786177). If I'm understanding correctly, the answer linked in both seems to rely upon the premise that the caller has called `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds` when creating the Key, and we have not done so. Additionally, the given solution seems to rely upon just deleting the key and generating a new one.

Below is our setup for the key for versions >= API 23. I've left out our key generation for versions older than 23 since we've primarily seen this on APIs >= 23.

```
private static final int RSA_KEY_SIZE = 2048;
private static final String CERT_SUBJECT_STRING = "CN=<COMPANY_NAME> Android App O=<COMPANY_NAME>";
private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";

try {
        String alias = KEY_NAME;
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);

        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(RSA_KEY_SIZE, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB)
            .setCertificateNotAfter(end.getTime())
            .setCertificateNotBefore(start.getTime())
            .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
            .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal(CERT_SUBJECT_STRING))
            .build();
        generator.initialize(spec);
        generator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

We then attempt to access the keys later via `keyStore.getEntry(KEY_NAME, null)`. Again, this works for a while but then will begin to throw the above exception.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced issues with stability in KeyStore.

The solution was to use for [private key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getKey(java.lang.String,%20char[]))

```
PrivateKey privKey = ks.getKey(alias, password)
```

And this to public key

```
PublicKey pubKey = ks.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
```

instead of [getEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getEntry(java.lang.String,%20java.security.KeyStore.ProtectionParameter))

```
ks.getEntry(alias, password)
```

The problem wasn't in the way you're creating the key but the way you're reading it.

Over more than a year never saw this issue again.