# How to reproduce or solve KeyStoreException?

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, crashlytics

Get crash with next description:

> Caused by java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Failed to obtain
> X.509 form of public key
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePublicKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:263)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyPairFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:303)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePrivateKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:324)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:388)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:105)
> at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1062)
> at com.mandarine.sai.sdk.tools.keystore.KeyStoreManager.getKeyPair(KeyStoreManager.java:117)
> at com.mandarine.sai.sdk.tools.keystore.KeyStoreManager.deleteKeyPairs(KeyStoreManager.java:222)
> at com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.common.ConnectionKeyBuilderKt.collectConnectionsAndKeys(ConnectionKeyBuilderKt.java:73)
> at com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.common.ConnectionKeyBuilderKt.collectConnectionsAndKeys(ConnectionKeyBuilderKt.java:41)
> at com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.list.AuthorizationsListViewModel.(AuthorizationsListViewModel.java:79)
> at com.mandarine.sai.app.ViewModelsFactory.create(ViewModelsFactory.java:102)

KeyStoreException: Invalid key blob

> Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid key blob
> at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1301)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePublicKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:265)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyPairFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:303)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePrivateKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:324)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:388)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:105)
> at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1062)
> at com.mandarine.sai.sdk.tools.keystore.KeyStoreManager.getKeyPair(KeyStoreManager.java:117)
> at com.mandarine.sai.sdk.tools.keystore.KeyStoreManager.deleteKeyPairs(KeyStoreManager.java:222)
> at com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.common.ConnectionKeyBuilderKt.collectConnectionsAndKeys(ConnectionKeyBuilderKt.java:73)
> at com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.common.ConnectionKeyBuilderKt.collectConnectionsAndKeys(ConnectionKeyBuilderKt.java:41)
> at com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.list.AuthorizationsListViewModel.(AuthorizationsListViewModel.java:79)
> at com.mandarine.sai.app.ViewModelsFactory.create(ViewModelsFactory.java:102)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
> at com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.list.AuthorizationsListFragment.setupViewModel(AuthorizationsListFragment.java:119)
> at com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.list.AuthorizationsListFragment.onCreate(AuthorizationsListFragment.java:65)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)

Here is code:

```
fun collectConnectionsAndKeys(
    repository: ConnectionsRepositoryAbs,
    keyStoreManager: KeyStoreManagerAbs
): Map<ConnectionID, ConnectionAndKey> {
    return repository.getAllActiveConnections().mapNotNull {
        it.getPrivateKeyForConnection(keyStoreManager)
    }.toMap()
}




  /**
     *  Get related private key for connection
     *
     *  @param connection Connection
     *  @return ConnectionAndKey
     */
    override fun createConnectionAndKeyModel(connection: ConnectionAbs): ConnectionAndKey? {
        return getKeyPair(connection.guid)?.private?.let { key ->
            ConnectionAndKey(connection, key)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get RSA key pair by the given alias
     *
     * @param alias - the alias name
     * @return KeyPair object
     */
    override fun getKeyPair(alias: String?): KeyPair? {
        val keyAlias = alias ?: return null
        val store = androidKeyStore ?: return null
        return (store.getKey(keyAlias, null) as? PrivateKey)?.let { privateKey ->
            val publicKey: PublicKey? = store.getCertificate(keyAlias).publicKey
            KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey)
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

So i write something like this:

```
override fun getKeyPair(alias: String?): KeyPair? {
    return try {
        val keyAlias = alias ?: return null
        val store = androidKeyStore ?: return null
        (store.getKey(keyAlias, null) as? PrivateKey)?.let { privateKey ->
            val publicKey: PublicKey? = store.getCertificate(keyAlias).publicKey
            KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey)
        }
    } catch (e: UnrecoverableKeyException) {
        null
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e)
        null
    }
}
```

But i don't understand why is my android keystore currently blocked on my XIAOMI phone?
I have seen similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36747600/6387618) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36846085/6387618), but deleting the key from keystore is not my solution.

Comment: Are you reading the keystore with the same APK/Bundle you used to write those values?

Comment: @FcoP. I'm not sure but I think so. Here is full code of my KeyStoreManager https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/b7964e86423e68cd02a081d3d3f1d8f3

Comment: I have the same problem with Redmi Note 8 pro update when it is updated to android 11.
The only solution that I have found is to remove and reinstall the app

Comment: yep,
Redmi Note 8 Pro

Answer (score 1):

try typing your password instead of autosave from ide, it is a known bug

Comment: Sorry, i don t understand your point.
I added some code, maybe it will be useful

Comment: this happens when you are generating signed apk and ide uses autosaved password of your keystore , is that your case too ?

Comment: it happens when i tried to get store in my func `getKeyPair`